# How to efficiently split a 2D space in cells such that each cell contains at most K points?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, data-structures

I have a dataset of 2D points (~500k of them) on which I'd like to perform some kind of quadrat count analysis. The basics of quadrat count is to split your 2D space into a regular grid (each cell has size `SxS`) and count the number of points in each cell.

For some reason, I'd like to do a slight variation of that : instead of using a regular grid, I want to build the grid such that each cell contains **at most** `K` points.

What I did is the following: I start with the whole space, and divide it in 4 cells (by "cutting" each dimension in half). Then, I count the number of points in each cell. For those that contain more than `K` points, I divide them again, etc., until I'm done.

I tried both recursive and iterative implementations of this simple algorithm, but none performed well when applied to the whole dataset. The main bottleneck is the counting part, obviously, so I was wondering what kind of datastructure would allow me to do this efficiently ?

(For now, I'm just using "conditional indexing" in Python : `points = points[points[,1] > x1 and points[,1] <= x2 and points[,2] > y1 and points[,2] <= y2,]`)

Also, do you have maybe another idea on how I could build my grid ?

EDIT: In other words, what kind of data structure could I use to quickly count (and retrieve) the points that fall within a given rectangle `((x1, y1), (x2, y2))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't complete but it might point you in the right direction.

Instead of starting big and going small, start small and go big.

Divide your space into, say, 100x100 cells. Count the number in each cell (this is exactly O(n), you count each cell once.)

From there on out you don't need to count cells. You can create CellGroups to count what cells it has, and from there I would use an algorithm to combine cells into CellGroups.

You might consider an approach that takes two small cells to merge them and recalculates.

```
while(true) {
    take the smallest cellgroup
    compare it to each other cellgroup starting with the second smallest
    go up the list until you find two adjecent cell groups
    if you find a match
        merge them
        update the cellgroup size rankings
        repeat the process (continue the while(true)
    otherwise
        break out, you're done merging cells

}
```

Comment: Well, the result will not be the same. With the big to small technique, I will end up with cells having few, or no data points at all (because if points are very clustered, the first "cuts" of a big cell will end up with only one "subcell" containing all points, and the three others none). The small to big method you're describing, on the other hand, will merge all empty cells with neighbors. In other words, it will give the smallest number of cells such that each cell has at most K points.

Comment: I don't say that one method is better than the other, though. Just that they're not the same. I am not sure if yours makes senses for what I'm trying to do (I'll have to think about it).

Comment: But you would continue to merge cells until you reached a state where cells cannot be merged further. It may not be the most ideal state (i.e. it may be possible to split the cells in a different way that yields fewer final cellgroups) but it should be a fairly decent method.

Comment: Right. Thus, with your method, you will end up with no empty cells, and most of the cells having at least K/2 points. With mine, however, you end up with empty cells, and also cells having few points.

Comment: Also, there's nothing that says you can't split the largest cells into two groups either, combining the two approaches.

Comment: Yes, I'll look into that. I was wondering if there was some kind of datastructure that would allow me to quickly retrieve points that are inside a given rectangle? I'll add this to my question.

Comment: Well, there you go ;) ! Now I know how it's called... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with Python, but if you run through entire array for each quadrant, it can be improved:

After each splitting group points according to quadrant they correspond to. When splitting further a quadrant analyse only corresponding subarray. This may speed up counting.

Also since you are OK with irregular grid, you may consider selecting separation lines always diving points into equal groups (horizontal and vertical splitting should be done separately for this).

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and it helped (in the recursive case). But the problem is that with the recursion, I was hitting the maximum recursion depth of Python...

Comment: The last thought about dividing into separate groups may limit recursion to log(number of points). Also you may switch to own stack...